# Explanation of code snippet regarding how to pass an array as a function argument using a pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Following is the **CODE SNIPPET** to add elements of an array in C language!

**Main** function :

```
int main ()
{
    int a[3]={10,11,12}; 
    printf("%d\n" , arraysum(a,3) );
}
```

**Arraysum** function definition :

```
int arraysum (int *addr , int len )
{
    int sum = 0, i ;
    for (i=0 ; i<len ; i++)
        sum += addr[i];
    return sum ;
}
```

**OUTPUT :** 33

**QUESTIONS** : I know that in the `main` function the base address of the array `a` is passed to pointer `addr` , but after that I am unable to understand how following statement is working :

```
sum+=addr[i];
```

**Q1 :** Next ,  addr was a pointer variable , then how am I using it as an array in `arraysum` function ?

**Q2 :** More importantly when I passed base address of array `a` to the pointer then how come i am able to access all the elements of array `a` through it ?

Comment: 1. `sum += addr[i]` = `sum = sum + addr[i]` if this makes more  sense for you. 2. You an use the array in the function arraysum, because it still exist and you have the pointer to the first element in the memory 3. You can loop though the addresses in the memory because the elements of the array are stored like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: You can index pointers as if they were arrays (in fact, array indexing really is pointer indexing). So

```
addr[i]
```

is the same as `*(addr + i)`

Q2: because when you pass an array to a function expecting a pointer, the array decays to a pointer to its first element. So `addr` points to the first element of `a`. This is a simplified version of the same phenomenon, without a function call:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3}; // size 3 array of int
int * p = a;         // OK: a decays to int*. p points to &a[0]
p[0];                // same as a[0]
```

Note that despite everything, `a` and `p` have different types. `a` is a size 3 array of `int`. The type contains size information. `p` is just a pointer to `int`. It can point to an element of an array, but it can also point to a single `int`.

Answer (score 3):

> Q1 : Next , addr was a pointer variable , then how am i using it as an array in arraysum function ?

Actually, you have this backwards. The subscript operator `[]` applies to pointers, not to arrays. Huh? What am I on about? Well when you do `array[i]` where `array` is an array, the array actually *decays* to a pointer to its first element. So you are always applying `[]` to a pointer. In your case, `addr` is *already* a pointer to its first element.

> Q2 : More importantly when i passed base address of array a to the pointer then how come i am able to access all the elements of array a through it ?

When you do `something[i]`, it is equivalent to `*((something) + (i))`. This is just basic pointer arithmetic. Take the pointer pointing at the first element, increment the pointer by `i`, then dereference it.

It is because of this pointer arithmetic that we can access all of the elements of an array through a pointer to one of its elements.

Answer (score 2):

Basically  int *addr point to the first element in your array. So if you say addr[i] it equals to *(addr + i), which points to the ith element.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `plain array` to function, it decays to a `pointer`. So, we would talk about `pointer` from now onwards.

If you get a `pointer` to memory location `(ptr)` what all things you could do with it:-

```
de-reference it
     *ptr

increment it 
     ++ptr;
```

etc...

So, this function doesn't know you have an array. You happen to behave in this function as this `pointer is pointer into as array`. That means you can increment it to get to the next element of an array as array elements are in consecutive memory location. However, you have to ensure that you don't cross the bound. For that you explicitly pass `size of array` to this function.